# Login with email (WP Modal Login)

Tags: plugins, login, wp-login-form

I'm trying to fork this plugin to use the user email to login, as opposed to Username.

The plugin is http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-modal-login/

Is there a nice way to do this, perhaps by a filter to get this plugin to work with email credentials?

I've tried using this filter:

```
function custom_login() {
  $data = array();        
  $data['user_login']     = sanitize_user( $_REQUEST['username'] );
  $data['user_email']     = sanitize_user( $_REQUEST['user_email'] );
  $data['user_password']  = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['password'] );
  $data['rememberme']     = sanitize_text_field( $_REQUEST['rememberme'] );
  $data['user_login']     = sanitize_user( $_REQUEST['user_email'] );
  $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
  if ( is_wp_error($user) )
    echo $user->get_error_message();
}
// run it before the headers and cookies are sent
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

Comment: Do you want to FORCE email-only log in? or just allow email log in ALSO?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm using this simple action, and it works like a charm. :)

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#111223) User Login with Mail Address */
    add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'wpse111223_login_with_email_address' );
function wpse111223_login_with_email_address( $username ) {
    $user = get_user_by_email( $username );
    if ( ! empty( $user->user_login ) )
        $username = $user->user_login;

    return $username;
}
```

It hooks to wp_authenticate and enables email login to the WordPress Authentication system, so it should work with any plugin. I use it successfully with **Login with Ajax** plugin.

:)

Later-edit: For those who don't know where to put the snippet of code, it should go in your theme's `functions.php` or a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I use this basic method to enable email log in, similar to another answer, but I think it is cleaner to test first:

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'custom_allow_email_login', 20, 3);
function custom_allow_email_login( $user, $username, $password )
{
    if ( is_email($username) )
    {
        $user = get_user_by_email( $username );
        if ( $user ) $username = $user->user_login;
    }
    return wp_authenticate_username_password( null, $username, $password );
}
```

Unfortunately, if you want to change the label on the form, you have to either use Javascript or create your own log in page, with its own, customizable form.

Using Javascript:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_login_enqueue_scripts' );
function custom_login_enqueue_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_action( 'login_form', 'custom_change_username' );
function custom_change_username()
{
    echo "\n" . '
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $("label").html(function(index,html){
                return html.replace("Username", "Username or Email");
            });
        });
    </script>' . "\n";
}
```

And you can use [wp_login_form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_form) to include a log in form on your own page.